# How to pause audio playback in webview when the activity is paused?

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a webview and on the `onPause` of my activity I am calling `webview.onPause()` however it does not seem to work, the audio keeps on playing. The website I am using to test this is this website:

http://hpr.dogphilosophy.net/test/

So what is the right way to do this? I'm on android 4.3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience of WebViews, you cannot directly interface with the contents of the displayed WebView. In other words, there is no way to pause a website.

I do not know what your app is intended to do, but maybe in the onPause of the activity/fragment you could re-direct the webview to display a blank site or someplace that has no audio???

Otherwise, if you will be developing the website as well, you could make some JavaScript that controls the audio playback, that you can interface with in the WebView if implemented correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to stop / resume these threads by calling the onPause / onResume on the webview.

Those are however hidden, so you will need to do it through reflection. The following code worked for me:

```
Class.forName("android.webkit.WebView").getMethod("onPause", (Class[]) null).invoke(webView, (Object[]) null);
```

Where webView is the instance of WebView.

Also see: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10282